# get domain name (base url without protocol)

Tags: cakephp

How to get app domain name? (I mean base url without protocol `http://` or `https://`)

So if app is installed on 'http://sub.example.com/app', I want to get 'sub.example.com'.

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/'.basename(dirname(APP))`...? For URL with protocol, `Router::fullbaseUrl().'/'.basename(dirname(APP))`...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is the PHP global **$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']** - this will return the domain without protocol, but won't give you a sub-directory, e.g. if your app is at www.domain.com/myapp/app.

Assuming you are referring to a CakePHP app (given the tag on the question), you can use the following constant upto version 2.4:

> FULL_BASE_URL

In version 2.4 you can use:

> Router::fullbaseUrl()

This returns the base URL with http:// or https://. You can then do a regex replace to get rid of that part.

Try:

```
function replace_http($url) {
    $pattern = "https{0,1}:\/{2}";
    return preg_replace($pattern, "", $url);
}

$baseUrl = replace_http(Router::fullBaseUrl());
```

Comment: it's deprecated since version 2.4. Also, it includes protocol.

Comment: Updated with 2.4-specific version

Comment: thanks, but `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` is right (case-sensitive)

Comment: It doesn't include sub directory though. @Abhishek's answer below is probably more complete and less wheel-reinventing.

Answer (score 1):

I use this in my config.php/bootstrap.php which is located in config folder to get url app domain with folder

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].dirname(dirname(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])));
```

Comment: This looks very complex... `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/'.basename(dirname(APP))` will return same thing... In fact, with a slash in between which you had missed...

Answer (score 0):

```
parse_url(Router::fullBaseUrl(), PHP_URL_HOST)
```